# What is the best Shafarevich's algebraic geometry book for beginners?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, book-recommendation

What is the difference between these books from Shafarevich: [Basic Algebraic Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540082646) and [Basic Algebraic Geometry 1: Varieties in Projective Space](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642379559)? I suppose the second one is better for beginner students, am I right?

Thanks

Comment: The first volume is an old version of a book whose newer edition has been split into two volumes,  of which you mention the first. The new version is  better,  because it contains much more material and benefits from the new translator's (Miles Reid) great mathematical  expertise.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Can you explicit the other reasons and what do you mean by "richer"? Thank you!

Comment: More pages,  more material. The level is the same however, so the difference is not suitability for a beginner.